# Tabbed form navigation in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, navigation

How to navigate in .net forms? I need to navigate to a page based on selection from a list of options. But creating new forms for each selection doesn't look good. So how to make a better navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for a docking windows library? My team uses this one

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/

it is free and suits our needs. It allows you to stack new forms in a "tabbed" way, the user can close the forms/tabs he does not need any more, and you can customize the behaviour in several ways.

Comment: I can't figure out how to use it in VS2008. Can u plse tell how??

Comment: @Vicky: download Version 2.4.0 (source), extract everything to a folder, open the SLN file in VS, compile it and study the examples contained. So where's your problem?

Comment: No problem. Got it... I missed the point that we can download the source code :D My mistake...

Answer (score 1):

How about System.Windows.Forms.TabControl ? You can create and fill the tabs at design time.

Comment: That's the exact way I want, but Can a Tab be configured to work like in a browser's open in new tab option? Like on clicking an option the option will open in new tab??

Comment: Everything you do in the designer, you can also do at runtime. Not just the tabbed control, literally everything. So yes, you can add a new tab, set up its text, and put any child controls in it.

Comment: Although it looks like the built-in TabControl doesn't feature an X/close button. You can try a custom button, or look for a free, improved TabControl library.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating new tab(System.Windows.Forms.TabControl) instance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984280(v=vs.71).aspx) on the fly(runtime) like on linklable click and also if you want to check whether it already opened then try iterating with TabControl's all Tabs.